# how to get json values inside an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this data.json file and I need to get the values of the "hashtags" it is 10,000 json datas in my file so I include only the important one..

```
var data =
[
{
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [
            {
                "text": "Hope",
                "indices": [
                    0,
                    5
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "USA",
                "indices": [
                    6,
                    10
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "Youth",
                "indices": [
                    11,
                    17
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "sex",
                "indices": [
                    51,
                    55
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "condoms",
                "indices": [
                    94,
                    102
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "STD",
                "indices": [
                    120,
                    124
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "HPV",
                "indices": [
                    135,
                    139
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [
            {
                "text": "starbucks",
                "indices": [
                    3,
                    13
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
  }
]
```

So I have here a hashtags which I want to get ONLY the text and if it is a null it will not get anything.. I can't get the values and I don't know how to iterate it because I am not familiar in json.. here is my code by the way in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#hashtagBtn").click(function() 
   {
      $("#theTweets").html(graphHashtag());
   });
});



function graphHashtag()
{
   var getHashtags = [];

   $.each(data, function(i, obj)
   { 
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty("text") && data[i].lang == "en" && data[i].entities.hashtags != null)   
          getHashtags.push(obj.entities.hashtags[i].text);
   });

   return getHashtags;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to parse the JSON with `JSON.parse(data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use javascript for this kind of task... no jQuery wrapping is required

```
function graphHashtag()
{
   var tags= [];

   for (var i in data)
   {
       // data[i] is an object

       for (var j in data[i].entities.hashtags)
       {
           var text = data[i].entities.hashtags[j].text;

           if (text) tags.push(text);
       }
   }
   return tags;
}
```

i omitted some validations, but if every main object will have the **entities** and **hashtags** properties there shouldn't be any problem

Comment: great! **JSON** is the shortage of JavaScript Object Notation.. so the name implies that it designed to be manipulated using JavaScript